# Validate model without associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `user` that `has_one` `business`

At certain times I want to validate user on its own without taking into account business.

At the moment if

`user.business.valid?` is `false`

this will make `user.valid?` also `false` even if the `user` record on its own is valid.

If in `user.rb` I do `has_one :business, :validate => false` it will not take business into account when validating `user`, but it will then always do it, which is what I dont want.

What is the syntax to call the validation on user without taking the business association into account?

If I do `user.business(validate: false).valid?` it will ignore the validation on `business` and `user`. The above will be true even if user is invalid.

Any ideas?

## Update:

Validations:

`user.rb`

`validates :first_name, presence: true`

`business.rb`

`validates :name, presence: true`

Using rails5.0.0.rc1

Comment: Can u post the validations that you have in model?

Comment: `user.rb` `validates :first_name, presence: true`

Comment: `business.rb` `validates: name, presence: true`

Comment: You can make a custom validation method.

Comment: @chasenyc The validations is of course more complicated than that - did end up making a custom validation as you suggested but still sure there should be a syntax for specifying as in above use case